# Xpath validation on single root element with different namespaces elements

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-2.0

Quick question on xpath. I need to validate root element "Consumers" together with it's namespace declaration. This xml can vary as follows depends on the broker it mediates through.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ss:Consumers xmlns:ss="http://xml.mycompany.com/XMLSchema"/>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Consumers xmlns="http://xml.mycompany.com/XMLSchema"/>
```

I need to write single xpath expression to validate both scenarios. Please help.

Comment: What do you mean, "Validate?" That the element exists?

Comment: Yes. I'm looking for a common validation for both scenarios mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XPath, different prefix doesn't matter, as long as it points to the same namespace URI. Even empty prefix i.e by using default namespace declaration means the same.

For example, given that I have declared a prefix `foo` bound to the correct namespace uri in [xpathtester](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath), like so * :

```
foo="http://xml.mycompany.com/XMLSchema"
```

the following XPath would return 1 element in either scenarios :

```
//foo:Consumers
```

*) note that declaring prefix for use in XPath varies from platform to platform. This one is specific to xpathtester

---

For the sake of demo, I have put the two scenarios within a `<root>` element, and the XPath returns both `Consumers` elements (run the demo [here](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/1dd7a208c32a42507df4f80d7bc085d0)).

**Sample XML :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
<ss:Consumers xmlns:ss="http://xml.mycompany.com/XMLSchema"/>
<Consumers xmlns="http://xml.mycompany.com/XMLSchema"/>
</root>
```

**Output :**

```
<ss:Consumers xmlns:ss="http://xml.mycompany.com/XMLSchema"/>

<Consumers xmlns="http://xml.mycompany.com/XMLSchema"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write an XPath expression that will check the namespace URI, and the local-name of the element, like so:

`/*[local-name()='Consumers' and namespace-uri()='http://xml.mycompany.com/XMLSchema']`

This avoids the need to register any namespace prefixes with your XPath implementation.
This XPath will also work in XPath 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

My general recommendation if you have to write code that processes two XML variants which are identical (or largely identical) except for the namespace URI is to start by normalizing the namespace URI, that is, do a transformation on the documents so that they all use the same namespace URI. The difference in namespace is then localized to one place in your code, and doesn't permeate your entire application.